# how to specifiy the terminal of NI USB-6210 with python

Tags: python, nidaqmx

I am using NI DAQ USB-6210.
I am trying to make the program that can be applied counter output with python.

```
import nidaqmx
from nidaqmx.constant import AcquisitionType

Counter1 = nidaqmx.Task()
counter1 = Counter1.co_channels.add_co_pulse_chan_freq(
    counter = "Dev2/ctr0",
    units = FrequencyUnits.HZ,
    freq = rate)
#counter1.co_pulse_term = "Dev2/PFI7"

Counter1.timing.cfg_implicit_timing(
      sample_mode = AcquisitionType.CONTINUOUS,
      samps_per_chan = 1000)

Counter1.start()
h = input('ok ? >>')
Counter1.close()
```

NI DAQ is working, counter signal is applied from PFI4.
When I removed #, it must be applied from PFI7.
but it is shown the error below.

"DaqError: Destination terminal to be routed could not be found on the device."

my question is how to select the terminal I want use?
please tell me solution to this problem?

Comment: check manual of the device for pin of  "Dev2/ctr0", ctr0 terminal

Comment: thank you very much for your comment.
We have already checked the behavior of terminal.
This DAQ has PFI4 to 7 for output.
We have demonstrated to output from PFI7 with LabVIEW system.